# Laravel, javascript add rows table class select not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have this code which works fine. my problem is that when i go to add one or more rows in the table with the button
the select:

```
<select name = "product_id_product []" id = "product_id_product '. $ request-> count_product.'" class = "form-control js-select2" required>
```

it is as if it does not take the "js-select2" class

if instead I insert it manually in the index bypassing the whole class it works
I just can't figure out how to do it ..

index.blade:

```
<div class="card-body" style="text-align: center;">
                          <button type="button"  name="aggiungi_prodotto" id="aggiungi_prodotto" class="btn btn-primary aggiungi_prodotto" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="mdi mdi-playlist-plus"></i>Aggiungi Prodotto</button> 
                          <button type="button"  name="aggiungi_accessorio" id="aggiungi_accessorio" class="btn btn-success aggiungi_accessorio" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="mdi mdi-playlist-plus"></i>Aggiungi Accessorio</button> 
                          <button type="button"  name="aggiungi_servizio" id="aggiungi_servizio" class="btn btn-warning aggiungi_servizio" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="mdi mdi-playlist-plus"></i>Aggiungi Servizio</button> 
                          <button type="button"  name="aggiungi_riga" id="aggiungi_riga" class="btn btn-danger aggiungi_riga" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="mdi mdi-playlist-plus"></i>Aggiungi Riga</button> <br/><br/><br/>

                          <div class="form-row">

                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-hover ">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th width="50%">Prodotto</th>
                                    <th width="10%">Quantità</th>
                                    <th width="10%">Acconto</th>
                                    <th width="10%">Costo</th>
                                    <th width="10%">Sconto TOT</th>
                                    <th width="10%">Azioni</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="prodottiRows">
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>



            
                             </div>

                                
                          </div>

                          <hr>
                        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var count_prodotto = 0;

    $(document).on('click', '#aggiungi_prodotto', function(){
        count_prodotto = count_prodotto + 1;
        
    var categorieID = document.getElementById('categorie_id').value;
    var brandID = document.getElementById('brand_id').value;
    var modelloID = document.getElementById('modello_id').value;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ route('autocomplete.fetch_prodotti') }}",
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name=csrf-token]').val(),
          'categorie_id':categorieID,
          'brand_id':brandID,
          'modello_id':modelloID,
          'count_prodotto':count_prodotto
        },
        success:function(data){
           $('#prodottiRows').append(data);          
      }
      });
        
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function fetch_prodotti(Request $request)
    {

      $products = Product::with('Multitenantable')
        ->where("stato_prodotto",'1')
        ->where("categorie_id",$request->categorie_id)
        ->where("brand_id",$request->brand_id)
        ->where("modello_id",$request->modello_id)
        ->pluck("nome_prodotto","id");
        
       

        $prodotti = '
        <tr id="row_prodotto'.$request->count_prodotto.'">
        <td><select name="product_id_prodotto[]" id="product_id_prodotto'.$request->count_prodotto.'" class="form-control js-select2" required>
        <option value="">Seleziona Prodotto</option>';

        foreach ($products as $key => $product) {

          $prodotti .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$product.'</option>';
          # code...
        }

        $prodotti .='</select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantita_prodotto[]" id="quantita_prodotto'.$request->count_prodotto.'" class="form-control" value="0" required /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="acconto_prodotto[]" id="acconto_prodotto'.$request->count_prodotto.'" class="form-control" value="0"  required /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="costo_prodotto[]" id="costo_prodotto'.$request->count_prodotto.'" class="form-control" value="0" required /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sconto_prodotto[]" id="sconto_prodotto'.$request->count_prodotto.'" class="form-control" value="0" required /></td>
        <td data-column="Rimuovi"><button type="button" name="remove_prodotto" id="'.$request->count_prodotto.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_prodotto">Rimuovi</button></td>
        </tr>';

        

        return response()->json($prodotti);
        

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not taking the class?

Comment: that the select box is a classic select box without any type of associated css

Comment: I mean what is the issue? Where is it not taking *"js-slect2"* class?

Comment: when I hit the add product button it adds this to me:
<tr id="row_prodotto'.$request->count_prodotto.'">
            <td><select name="product_id_prodotto[]" id="product_id_prodotto'.$request->count_prodotto.'" class="form-control js-select2" required>
            <option value="">Seleziona Prodotto</option>';
            <td data-column="Rimuovi"><button type="button" name="remove_prodotto" id="'.$request->count_prodotto.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_prodotto">Rimuovi</button></td>
            </tr>

but the select box is as if it didn't have the css style

Comment: In that case you need to inspect the element and check where the css is not working. Maybe it need to change the selectors a little or maybe need to add some more selectors. Its a css issue

Comment: but if that row that is generated I insert it in the index directly, the style of the class works well
it is as if the class had to be called once added via javascript

Comment: I solved I had to initialize the class like this:
$ ('# product_id_product'+count_prodotto). select2 ();

Comment: I see... So the newly created select box was not being initialized. Well anyways great work 